# navigating from one tab to other

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i do have a page which is created in PHP. This page includes a menu tab which consists of tabs called as Dash,Project.the dash tab consists of the table which shows some data in it.the scenario is like when i click on any one of the row of the table in dash tab it navigates to Project tab which consists of simple form and the data from the dash tab gets filled to form which is in project tab.but my problem is it remains on the same tab Which is Dash.I want that after clicking on the table in the dash it must shows the project tab but it is showing the Dash tabs content.i guess it is kept as Active that's why it is happening.

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#dash" data-toggle="tab">Dash</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#projects" data-toggle="tab">Projects</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" style="padding-bottom: 9px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="dash">
            <?php include "dash.php"; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="projects">
            <?php include "project.php"; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the code for dash tab from where it is navigating is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#" data-bind="attr:{value:id,title:projname,href:root+'projects/project/'+id},text:projname">
    </td>
    <td data-bind="text:enddate"></td>
    <td data-bind="text:status"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you include the jQuery code and the CSS you are using for your tabs pls?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the below.

```
$('#tabbable').tabs('select', $('#projects'));
$('#tabbable').tabs('select', $('#dash'));
```

Comment: @user1920656, as Barbs mentions in the comments, include more code in your Question to see what you've done.